# Determining the size of a subgroup of H

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Given that $|GL_{2}(Z_{5})|=480$ find the index of $H$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_5)$.

$$
H=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \\ \end{pmatrix}  \\a,c \neq 0 , \\a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}_5
$$

I proved in an earlier question that $H$ is in fact a subgroup of 
$GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_5)$.

I am having difficulty determining how to find the size of $H$. $H$ is not a special linear group because the determinant of H is not always 1, so I cannot find the size of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_5)$ to simply index against the size of $GL_2(Z_5)$, $480$.

What is the best way to go about determining the number of elements in $H$?

Comment: How many choices are there for $a$?  How many choices are there for $b$?  What about $c$?

Comment: a,c have four choices and b has five choices.

Comment: Your answer is all you need to figure out the size of $H$.

Comment: size of $H$ will be $80$, I guess, it's all about determining the number of different matrices with the given conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It is a rough way to calculate but hope  it gives you some idea.

So first $H$ contains matrices of the form $$
A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \\ \end{pmatrix},  \ a,c \neq 0 , \ a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}_5
$$

So we have $4$ choices for each $a$ and $c$ and $5$ choices for $b$. First consider all the possible choices where $a=c$, like $(a,c)=(1,1)$, $(2,2)$ etc. Then each different choice of $b$ will give different matrices , and there will be $5$ different matrices. So for $4$ choices of $(a,c)$ where $a=c$ we have $20$ different matrices. Similarly for choices of $a\neq c$, we have $10$ different matrices each time, and total $60$ when $a\neq c$. So total matrices are $20+60=80$. So $|H|=80.$

Comment: @MichaelBurr No I mean $a\neq c$ that is in the sense values of $a$ and $c$ is different. We are already given with $a\neq 0$ and $c \neq 0$